# Can't get numbers from image with python, Tesseract and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

i have to get numbers from a water-meter image usign python tesseract and opencv.
I have tried to change the --psm but it's doesn't work.

Here the image without modification :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOaEW.jpg)

Here the outpout image :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ437.png)

I need your help guys, i'm starting python and i'm already blocked :'(

My code :

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib
import requests
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\Hymed\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

col = Image.open("pts.jpg")
gray = col.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255, '1')
bw.save("cp19.png")


image = cv2.imread('cp19.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = 255 - cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Blur and perform text extraction
thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)
img1 = np.array(thresh)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img1, config='--psm 11 digits')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nearly finished the task.

I use the divide operation, after the `GaussianBlur`.

```py
div = cv2.divide(gray, thresh, scale=192)
```

Result:

[image]

When I read from the image:

```py
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(div, config='--psm 11 digits')
print(data)
```

Result:

```py
00000161
```

Code: (Just added `div = cv2.divide(gray, thresh, scale=192)` rest are your code)

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np

col = Image.open("TOaEW.jpg")
gray = col.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 128 else 255, '1')
bw.save("cp19.png")

image = cv2.imread('cp19.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = 255 - cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Blur and perform text extraction
thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3, 3), 0)

div = cv2.divide(gray, thresh, scale=192)  # added

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(div, config='--psm 11 digits')
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks its amazing. Can i apply this on different water-meter ?

Comment: I think so, but I can't guarantee

Comment: I guess for similar images you can use this, but for image having different intensities you have to do some more pre-processing.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to read the number from an image using Tesseract. Except the numbers shown in the first line, it also returned an unidentified symbol in the second line. I don't understand what I did wrong. Here is the code and the results
[code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ain9M.png)

This is the image I extracted the number from:
[Image used for number extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3GLb.png)